# New SDK14 Library Projects are always gone after eclipse restart

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, library-project

This is something that's annoying me since updating to the latest ADT and SDK14.

I do have a lot of library projects and their references were converted from xxx_src folders to a 'Library Projects' folder during upgrade to the latest Android Development Environment. Everything works until the next Eclipse restart. These 'Library Projects' folders are gone after Eclipse restart - always.

So I have to right click all referencing projects one at a time --> Properties --> Android --> Remove the library project (it's still declared in there) --> Apply --> add the library project again --> Apply. Now the folder 'Library Projects' is back again - til the next Eclipse restart.

What's wrong here? Is there something that I can fix to make these 'Library Projects' folders stay permanent? Developing for Android is pure pain currently.

Comment: I don't know, but now I'll wait some time before upgrading XD.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using the following steps:

1. Remove the library references from Project Properties->Android.
2. Close Eclipse
3. Remove the hidden .settings folder in the project folder
4. open eclipse and re-add the library references from Properties->Android again.

The new Library Projects folder now persists properly across restarts of eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

There are rafts of issues upgrading to ADT14 if you use Android Library Projects

These links cover some bits of it.

[How install old ADT13 in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877361/how-install-old-adt13-in-eclipse/7897723#7897723)

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21031

Bottom-line is I recommend a completely clean install of Eclipse, ADT and the SDK - copy your sourcecode into a new workspace and Import it - go through it (see those links) removing and re-adding all your Android Libraries, check, tidy and order your Build Path properly and you'll be AOK

It's not a trivial task tho - work on copies because you could find yourself unable to deploy code until you wrestle this stuff into shape...

Comment: The thread you mention is from me too. I did re-install all components lots of times. I even did delete the .android folder, the metadata folder and so on. Now after one week of installing and stopped development its working again. Don't asking me why - I think its the step from Helios to Indigo.

Comment: Several people are suggesting that - but if you look at the Google thread a lot of the early reports are from Indigo users...

The step to ADT14 needs planning -basically - it would be nice if Google had a better mechanism to tell us about changes BEFORE we install their upgrades tho...

Answer (score 0):

Does someone still have this problem?

In my ADT-Version of Eclipse (From ADT Bundle from 2013_07_09) sometimes Android Libraries are removed suddenly without doing anything in the project settings.

I didn't solve that by following the same steps as user "DJPJ" has posted .

I solved it the following way:

1. Right click on Android Project -> Close Project
2. Right click on Android Project -> Open  Project

But this is only a temporary solution. It was the second time on my PC when the libs were suddenly removed from the android projects