# How install old ADT13 in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adt

We do have lots of problems with our Android Apps when using SDK14/ADT14. Currently we can't build none of our complex apps with lots of libraries and dependant projects (Resources are not updated even after Clean, Refresh, Forced Save, ...). We would like to go back to SDK13/ADT13.

SDK13 is in our backup repository. But we don't have the ADT13 plugins.

How can we direct Eclipse to download the old ADT13 plugins?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you got an android plugin installed? With it's a matter of few clicks. Try this link: http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

Comment: To get an older release of ADT?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710107/where-can-i-find-older-versions-of-eclipse-adt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to do this recently as well. Fortunately there's a hidden cache of old ADT versions, here's the link for the previous ADT release:

http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-12.0.0.zip

Then inside Eclipse you go to `Help -> Install new software -> Add... -> Archive ... -> choose the downloaded zip`. FYI: Unfortunately, you can't (or at least, I couldn't) revert to the previous SDK Manager and Tools version so easily (it insisted on getting itself upgraded before downloading the SDKs), I had to use an old copy of the folder I had lying around. Since you have SDK13 in your repo, you should be good to go.

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot. Seems that after ADT12 came ADT14 and after SDK13 came SDK14. I was always searching for ADT13. It's installing currently. Thanks.

Comment: If you need to the old SDK Tools (i.e. "platform-tools" folder), you can get it from here: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r07-windows.zip (replace "windows" with either "linux" or "macosx" depending on your OS).

Source: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you've updated both the SDK AND the ADT plugin in Eclipse - I forgot to do the latter and had the problems you've described.

SDK14/ADT14 introduced a lot of changes - the old ADT won't work with the new SDK and the new ADT doesn't work with the old SDK.

If you've done both and it's still not working then moyshe's link takes you to the relevant to stuff to download (just uninstall what you have already and install the older versions)

Comment: Yes, in the last few days I did re-install Eclipse and SDK and ADT several times. I used SDK14 and ADT14 all the time. We do have lots of problems here with the build process from within Eclipse (Android libraries, resources, ...).

Comment: It's odd - I had to reinstall ADT to get it to work (it refused to find resources from library projects) but it did eventually work.

In fact I think I upgraded ADT - then the SKD - then removed and reinstalled ADT again!

Comment: I think I just ran into the problem you're having - something to do with Library Projects missing JAR files???

All I did to fix it is go into Project Properties, Build Path, Libraries and there's a "Library Projects" container - REMOVE it.

Then goto your Android Libraries - remove them all - "Apply" - and then add them all back in again - and it will compile AOK!

Comment: For reference tho - you're far from alone and it seems ADT14 has some serious issues.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21031

I've managed to hack-around it for my current work, but I have one project which uses 6 Library Projects and I barely dare open that because I KNOW it will just implode

Comment: I can't count the Apply button hits I did to remove and add libraries. In all those years in Software Development this environment is the worst one. Libraries and Projects were playing pingpong here. I don't trust the results any longer. Are you sure that your resource changes to Libraries or Dependant Projects become compiled in?

Comment: The 2 projects I've worked-on are AOK - however I just brought-up my more complex stuff on the laptop (copied over) and they won't work at all under ADT14 - just an endless cycle of library-related errors as per the thread I listed above.

It's clearly borked - even those who manage to work around it say that the errors come back the next time you open-up the projects!!

Reverting to ADT12/SDK13 requires recovering all your source too tho - project files touched with ADT14 cannot be opened by Eclipse/ADT12 - it's a massive cockup...

Comment: Just a quick update - I created a completely new setup (Eclipse/ADT/SDK) and managed to get everything working using a mix of stuff from the Google Groups thread (listed in a comment above) - I'm not sure my posting a complete answer the problem here is appropriate but they have changed how Android Projects work and you do need to gut them out of your work completely and reinstall them.  It would be nice if they'd told us...

Answer (score 0):

Is your issue similar to this: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21201

Basically each time I open Eclipse, I have to remove all library projects from all projects using them, apply changes. Then re-add them manually. Then I can start working!

It's very probable that it's related to http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21031.

This is serious issues and I can't believe no-one from Google has responded yet!

Comment: Google style! Yes, this is part (1) of our problems. Part (2) of our problem is that none of our resource changes in library projects are build into the dependant projects. Even with Refresh, Clean, etc. they are not populated. Cleaning the library projects reports "manual changes, reverting to old version". Cleaning the dependant projects complaints about missing resource or library. We can't build our projects. So we're leaving Android Market until there's an upgrade to ADT14. Our projects worked before upgrading to ADT14 for over a year. And yes, we modified the switch() statements already.

Comment: Maybe this can also help, as it was quite a nightmare to make my workspace work again since the upgrade (what a pity!): i had to clean all my projects manually: removing all source linked projects, removing all library references (in both build path and android settings). Then I let it finish the build and complain about all this missing stuffs. Then back in Android settings, only added the needed libraries. Also had to remove any direct jar references (build path) that were already in the imported android libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this separate answer because of stuff I've learned from the Google Groups threads and my own experiments.  I realise it's not a straight answer to the OP's question but I think it's useful here regardless.

ADT14 has changed how Android Libraries are handled in Eclipse.  Instead of importing sourcecode (in LIBRARYNAME_SRC folders) it now compiles and brings over .JAR files (in a "Library Projects" folder).

To get my stuff working I built a complete new environment, installed the latest Eclipse/ADT/SDK, Imported my work and worked through all my projects from non-dependant libraries upwards - doing the following.

1 - remove all Android Libraries and 'Apply'

2 - remove all xxx_SRC folders from the Build-Path->Source tab

3 - remove any remaining xxx_SRC folders (should be empty anyway) from your Project.

4 - Add your Android Libraries back in again.

Another relates to Build Path Projects (non-Android ones).  Before, ADT did not mind if you had the same Build Path Project in multiple libraries - but it sure-as-hell does now!!  It crashes with "UNEXPECTED TOP LEVEL EXCEPTION"s, "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/yourlibrarypath" and "Conversion to Dalvik Format Failed" messages.

This prevents you deploying - to solve it, go through your libraries and ensure that Projects only appear on the Build Path ONCE.  I suspect that, previously, ADT actually may have need them duplicated and may even have created this duplication!?

Lastly, you have to ensure that Eclipse builds everything in the right order.  Again, this didn't matter before but it's why your projects fail if you 'clean' or change anything.  To do this you have 2 choices

1 - rename your projects so that they appear in alphabetical order from 'leaf' to 'root' (e.g. libraries < projects which use them).

2 - In Eclipse, use Windows->Preferences->General->Workspace->Build Order and specify all your libraries, in order. Anything not in that list is built afterwards so only libraries need be mentioned there.

Hope this helps someone