# Install old system image with Android Tools R21

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sdk-tools

I'm stumped after doing a fresh install of Android Development Tools r21. http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

I've installed this and I am looking to create an AVD for Android 2.1 (API 7) to test some things, but I cannot find an option to install the Android 2.1 system image. In fact, nothing prior to Android 4.0 is an available system image for an AVD.

I've installed the SDK Platform but it doesn't include the system image. Based on the *Official Add-on Sites*, I tried to go to https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img.xml but this is essentially an empty XML file.

I've also checked the ADT Known Issues http://tools.android.com/knownissues

Finally, from [How install old ADT13 in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877361/how-install-old-adt13-in-eclipse) I gleaned the possible add-on site of https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml, but that doesn't pull anything into the SDK Manager either.

Does anyone know how to get this working?

**Android SDK Manager**
[image]

**Android SDK Manager - Add-on Sites**
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've solved my own issue. Apparently starting in Android Developer Tools R21

- System images of Android 4.0 and newer

  - Installed by checking the **ARM EABI v7a System Image** box in the Android SDK Manager
- System images of older than Android 4.0

  - Installed by checking the **SDK Platform** box in the Android SDK Manager

This was the source of confusion.

Additionally you must restart Eclipse to get it to be an available option, which I didn't do.